# Module.4 exception when running a shadow jar, but works fine when not shadowed

Tags: java, gradle, shadowjar

I am using the johnrengelman shadow gradle plugin to package up my project into an executable jar. In this case, I seem to be getting some error related to the rsa crypto libraries, as seen below. Does anyone have suggestions on what I might need to exclude from the shadow jar to make this work?

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Problem loading Module.4
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.by.f(Unknown Source) ~[documentum.viewer-1.0-all.jar:na]
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.by.c(Unknown Source) ~[documentum.viewer-1.0-all.jar:na]
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.cf.a(Unknown Source) ~[documentum.viewer-1.0-all.jar:na]
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.ce.b(Unknown Source) ~[documentum.viewer-1.0-all.jar:na]
    at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.ce.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[documentum.viewer-1.0-all.jar:na]
    at com.rsa.jsafe.JSAFE_SecureRandom.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[documentum.viewer-1.0-all.jar:na]
```